# How do I fix "syntax error, unexpected end of file" on my edit.blade.php?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to add edit page to my laravel website using xampp, but when I try to run the link it's show "syntax error, unexpected end of file". This is the error that I get:

```
<?php echo $__env->make('master', \Illuminate\Support\Arr::except(get_defined_vars(), ['__data', '__path']))->render(); ?><?php /**PATH C:\xampp\htdocs\webLaravel\resources\views/edit.blade.php ENDPATH**/ ?>
```

Arguments
"syntax error, unexpected end of file"

i already tried to change my edit function on PostController.php

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $post = DB::table('posts')->where('id_kategori',$id)->get();
    return view('edit',['posts'=>$post]);
}
```

This is the button on my index.blade.php

```
 <td><a href="/post/edit/{{ $post->id_kategori }}"><button type="button" 
class="btn btn-edit stn-md">Edit </button></td>
```

This is the route that i create in web.php

```
Route::get('/post/edit/{id}','PostController@edit');
```

Comment: The error message will tell you what file is the problem.

Comment: missing closing `</a>` tag? `<td><a href="/post/edit/{{ $post->id_kategori }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-edit stn-md">Edit</button></a></td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you're getting data using `get()`, i would assume you are using `@foreach` to loop through the data in your table. You need to make sure you're closing the `@foreach` loop using `@endforeach` blade directive to close the loop. Also, make sure you are closing all the `@if` with `@endif` directives.

```
@foreach
.
.
.
.
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like from your code example that you are missing the closing A tag!

You also don't need to use a button and an A tag. Try this...

```
 <td>
      <a class="btn btn-edit stn-md" href="/post/edit/{{ $post->id_kategori }}"> Edit </a>
 </td>
```